# JAXB: need to set namespace dynamically

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb

JAXB annotated class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "group")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "description", "types" })
public class GroupElement implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private long id;
private String description;
private String name;
private List<TypeElement> types;

@XmlTransient
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement(name = "description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@XmlElement(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlElement(name = "type")
public List<TypeElement> getTypes() {
    return types;
}

public void setTypes(List<TypeElement> types) {
    this.types= types;
}
```

}

java-package.info

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.test.at/r1/v1" ,
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="cdr1", namespaceURI="http://www.test.at/r1/v1")})
```

JAXB marshalling:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Group.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(group, sw);
```

I need to set the namespace dynamically depending on the group. With the package-info approach I get the same namespace in every XML file.

I also tried

```
JAXBElement<Group> element = new JAXBElement<Group>(new 
QName(latestStructure.getNamespace(), "group", "cdr1"), 
Group.class, group);
```

But With this approach only the root element gets the namespace and prefix assigned.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue where I need to populate `@XmlSchema` dynamically because the `namespaces` are provided by the user dynamically. Can you please provide your answer on how did you achieve this in the `JAXB`? It would be great if you can provide some solution or sample.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove namespace info from the class and package, but create object factories with qualified names (so as many object factories as many namespaces),

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {
...
}
```

and then use the correct factory to initiate your context instead of the Group class:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
```

For me easier would be to again use beans without namespaces, marshall to namespace free xml and transform the xml using xslt to add correct "dynamic" namespace as required.

Comment: The namespaces are also created dynamically by users and stored in a database. Therefore I cannot use object factories.

Comment: @Zielu, Can you please provide the answer on how to achieve this when the `namespaces` are user-defined? I am also facing a similar issue where I the `namespaces` are provided by the user and I need to map them to `POJO` then using the `Jaxb` I need to marshal it.